# Cannot assign string from none one class to another

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

very noob in programming here, i have an activity **(control)** in android studio and a class **(MesageSender)** which extends AsyncTask ,
so i wanted to give a text in activity `control` via edittext and save that to a string in class `messagesender` and display it back to `control` in a textview , here is the code for my control (activity) and MessageSender (class)

below is code of **control activity**

```
public class controler extends AppCompatActivity {

    public MessageSender mmessagesender = new MessageSender();
    static EditText et;
    Button bt;
    static TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_controler);
        et= findViewById(R.id.editText);
        bt = findViewById(R.id.button);
        tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);


        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mmessagesender.ip = et.getText().toString();

            }
        });


        }






    }
```

Here `ip` is string from MessageSender class and `et` is edittext in controll activity

Below is code of **MessageSender class**

```
public class MessageSender extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {
    Socket s;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    PrintWriter pw;
    String ip;



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... Voids) {
        String message = Voids[0];
        try{
            s =new Socket(ip,123);
            if(ip != null){
                controler.tv.setText(ip);

            }
            else{
               controler.tv.setText("no ip");
            }

        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

the problem was i cannot see the textview `tv` in `control` change to what i gave in edittext `et`
any help is appreciated , thanks :)

Comment: Are these 2 classes in same package or different package? Apologies for the incorrect answer as i assumed you were getting compiler error. I have deleted the current answer.

Comment: They are from same package , and no problem I'm happy you're helping

Comment: Since there are 2 different threads, few things to look for: 1. When will `doInBackground` be called? If there is no relation between `onClick` and `doInBackground`, then if doInBackground is called first, then it will not see the value. 2. Even if the order of calls are correct, visibility of objects/values in reference may require additional constraints(`volatile` may help). My knowledge in Android specific event handler is limited.

Comment: Thanks dude ill look into to the program once again and see if it can get it corrected and let you know 

Comment: i have done some poking , but i still cant figure out the issue yet, what i did was calling the ``mmessagesender.execute();`` on the on click listener on ``control`` i clearly lack knowledge in this ill try to get better at it, thankyou :)